# Visual Studio Team Services change language

Tags: azure-devops

How can i change the language in my Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) account?
I can change the place where the site is beeing hosted, but not where i can change the language.

In the on-premises version (Team Foundation Server), you can change the language, why not in the cloud version

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change it at the following URL: https://app.vsaex.visualstudio.com/me?mkt=en-US&tab=edit

Select the Preferences Tab

[image: Preferences]

Comment: Thanks, but that take no affect :(

Comment: Me too, my boss don't speak english. The language setting doesn't work.

Comment: This seem unfortunate. I would really like a nice way to collaborate with my japanese company but if they cannot navigate then it becomes difficult

Comment: That url throws 404 Not found, I think is currently not available. Any ideas of when it will be on languages such as spanish? For some clients this is critical and they won't use VSTS unless it's on their language.

Comment: @GabrielPiffaretti - I've updated the link and screen shot - which shows español as a language.

Comment: Yes but that doesn't change the VSTS UI

Answer (score 3):

Now, Azure DevOps(VSTS) is only show English in the UI.

​There has been a related user voice here:

> **Localization support for Team Services**
>
> https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/365587/localization-support-for-team-services.html

Please feel free to vote that ticket.

Answer (score 0):

1. Login to your account
2. At the top right corner there is a square with your photo, click, and then
3. Click on My profile.
4. On the new page, at the right of your name click on "Edit profile"
5. On the new page, click on "Preferences"
6. On the new page, change your prefered language.

Comment: This is the same like the answer of @daveshaw ... and it still doesn't take affect.