# Setting up language in visual studio team services?

Tags: tfs, region

Please does somebody knows how to change langauge or region in Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) page :
Example : https://xxxxxxxxxxxx.visualstudio.com/_projects

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Team Services change language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461190/visual-studio-team-services-change-language)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click *your account icon* in the top-right corner and select **My Profile**, click **Edit Profile**, under preferences label, you could change the **Preferred Language**

[image]

[image]

There are 14 languages and a browser language, you could choose the one you need and save changes, it will take effect immediately.

Comment: That doesn't help

Comment: @Arthur  Which one are you using TFS or VSTS? Have you tried  reload the browser after setting changed?

Comment: VSTS, as the OP